# How to check value in JSON?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, json-extract

I need to check if the value is in this JSON field

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(my_column, '$[*]') = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 1 IN (JSON_EXTRACT(my_column, '$[*]'))
```

My field: [1,2,3,4]

RESOLUTION WORK:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE JSON_SEARCH(my_column, "one", "1") IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Pls show us what you have tried so far and what is the problem?

Comment: I tried this two query, but not work. I dont know why

Comment: I Need SELECT IF ANY VALUE IN JSON = 1

Comment: If you need to test JSON for **numeric** value presence then you'd either test the values extracted from the array one-by-one or parse the array to separate values and test them. Whereas the string-type values may be easily found by JSON_SEARCH.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE JSON_SEARCH(my_column, "one", "1") IS NOT NULL
```